# Eclipse insert mode

Tags: eclipse

I need help with eclipse insert mode.I am using eclipse on macbook pro and unable to come out of insert mode.Tried clicking the Smart Insert Mode,Shift+Cmd+I,restart eclipse but still it reverts back to Insert mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When you have an editor open you can double click on the word 'Insert' shown in the status line at bottom of the Eclipse window.

Answer (score -2):

Simply press <kbd>Insert</kbd> key to toggle between smart insert mode and overwrite mode.

Note that when you press <kbd>Insert</kbd> key text cursor will change

- smart insert mode  = LEAN CARET
- overwrite mode     = BLOCK CARET

And it is universal behaviour on all text editor not restricted to eclipse editor.

Is insert is not working for you? check this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29463/where-is-the-insert-key-on-a-macbook-air).

Comment: Macs do not have an insert key. I fear the answer is 'because the eclipse team forgot / did not realize that 'insert' is untypable on a mac, so you can't'. Note that the answer you linked to doesn't work either (Fn+Enter is not now and possibly has never been 'insert' on a mac. It certainly isn't on Monterey)